# Excluded the package from monkey testing is still crashing

Tags: android, android-monkey

I have added package in blacklist file and moved to certain location, but i still see same package crash even after adding in black list file (Crash is not consistent 1 or 2 times if i run for 10 times)

Any idea what is root cause for black listed package to crash.